# How to understand "/proc/[pid]/stack"?

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, pthreads

According to `proc` manual:

> /proc/[pid]/stack (since Linux 2.6.29)
>
> This file provides a symbolic trace of the function calls in
>                 this process's kernel stack.  This file is provided only if
>                 the kernel was built with the CONFIG_STACKTRACE configuration
>                 option.

So I write a program to test:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *thread_func(void *p_arg)
{
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid > 0) {
            wait(NULL);
            return 0;
        } else if (pid == 0) {
            sleep(1000);
            return 0;
        }
        return NULL;
}
int main(void)
{
        pthread_t t1, t2;

        pthread_create(&t1, NULL, thread_func, "Thread 1");
        pthread_create(&t2, NULL, thread_func, "Thread 2");

        sleep(1000);
        return 0;
}
```

After running, use `pstack` to check the threads of progress:

```
linux-uibj:~ # pstack 24976
Thread 3 (Thread 0x7fd6e4ed5700 (LWP 24977)):
#0  0x00007fd6e528d3f4 in wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000400744 in thread_func ()
#2  0x00007fd6e52860a4 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fd6e4fbb7fd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 2 (Thread 0x7fd6e46d4700 (LWP 24978)):
#0  0x00007fd6e528d3f4 in wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000400744 in thread_func ()
#2  0x00007fd6e52860a4 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fd6e4fbb7fd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 1 (Thread 0x7fd6e569f700 (LWP 24976)):
#0  0x00007fd6e4f8d6cd in nanosleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fd6e4f8d564 in sleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00000000004007b1 in main ()
```

At the same time, check `/proc/24976/stack`:

```
linux-uibj:~ # cat /proc/24976/stack
[<ffffffff804ba1a7>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[<00007fd6e4f8d6cd>] 0x7fd6e4f8d6cd
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

The `24976` process has `3` threads, and they all block on system call(`nanosleep` and `wait`), so all `3` threads now work in `kernel` space, and turn into **kernel threads** now, right? If this is true, there should be `3` stacks in `/proc/[pid]/stack` file. But it seems there is only `1` stack in `/proc/[pid]/stack` file.

How should I understand `/proc/[pid]/stack`?

Answer (score 6):

> How should I understand `/proc/[pid]/stack` ?

Taken from the [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) pages for `proc`:

> There are additional helpful pseudo-paths:
>
> [stack]
>   The initial process's (also known as the main thread's) stack.

Just below this, you can find:

> [stack:[tid]] (since Linux 3.4)
>
> A thread's stack (where the [tid] is a thread ID).
>   It corresponds to the /proc/[pid]/task/[tid]/path.

Which seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: After your hints, I get the answer: on Linux, thread is actually a process, so `/proc/[tid]/stack` will get the thread's kernel stack info, or use `/proc/[pid]/task/[tid]/stack`.

Answer (score 1):

Nan Xiao is right.
Thread kernel mode stack is under /proc/[PID]/task/[TID]/stack.

you are checking /proc/[PID]/stack, that's the main thread stack so you have only 1. Others are under task folder.

Answer (score -1):

That is for sleep locks.  You might also look at `perf -g`  to see spin locks including high system time.

Comment: What is this answer referring to with "That is for sleep locks"?